# How to mirror and sync one git repo to another git repo?

Tags: git

I have a remote repository A and I want to mirror to a new remote repository B. I also want to sync A to B regularly like daily. How can I do that?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One way is to add repo B to repo A as a remote repo. The command to do this would be run from repo A:

```
git remote add <repo B name> <repo B URL>
```

From there on you can push to  using the mirror option. The command to do this would be run from repo A too such as:

```
git push --mirror <repo B name>
```

This should push all your refs up to repo B. I hope this helps.